# Xamarin.Forms labels not working anymore, on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, label

I am making a Xamarin.Forms project, and I am in the end of my app, but something really strange have happened. My app starts up with no labels (!?), meaning they are invisible or not created at all. Everything else seems to be working, until I press a button that is supposed to change the label - when I do this, the app freezes. I get no exception in Visual Studio, though.

One problem is that my breakpoints in PLC code never hits, only those I place in the iOS code. However, the buttons not related to changing a label works, so I know the PLC code have been ran. If I let the app run for a little while, and then press the pause-button in VS debugging to see where in the code I am, it stops at

```
UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
```

.. in Main.cs. I dont know if this is correct or not, when I run on Android, I get a Break Mode - No code is currently running.

I have been trying for hours to debug, reinstall, restart, clean and rebuild, but nothing seems to help. My code works perfectly in Android, and it worked in iOS 1 week ago. Anyone have any ideas what is going on, or what I can do to debug some more? Or must I make a new project and try start over?

Edit: I have also tried different starting pages, and all are the same: all views loads except those with text in them. I have a page with an Editor in it, and I can write in it, but no text is appearing inside of it. Only button have visible text. I do not use a custom font for my labels, I have not specified anything.

Answer (score 0):

Waking up fresh in the morning, I found my issue in 15 minutes..

After altering my Google search to TextView iOS instead of Label Xamarin, I found much more answers. [Thanks to this question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840147/uitextview-dont-show-text)

Basically, changing anything on the labels in the constructor of the page (even after InitializeComponent()), will mess up the view. I moved my code outside of the constructor (in the protected override void OnAppearing() method), and now it is working again.

The freeze part was not related - this was my custom menu that covered my screen with an invisible layout eating up all clicking events. A bit confusing, none of these issues are present in Android, but there you go.